# Installing Kali Linux wifi AC driver without ethernet

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, ethernet, iwlwifi

I know Linux pretty well, and I know how to use Kali Linux. But when I boot it, it can't connect to my wifi AC.
Apparently, to fix this there's some stuff about ethernet cables and access the wifi and run installation commands...
While I know security research and Linux, I don't know a thing about using ethernet. I've tried to connect it to another computer and whatnot and it doesn't work. All other distros I've tried connect to my wifi adapter just fine.

Ultimately, is there a way I can fix this without fidgeting with ethernet?

Note: It has a message in the installer boot where it asks for the driver files. 1: I don't know where to find them and 2: I don't know how to give them.

My wifi AC is:
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve: Plug the computer into ethernet *while* running the installer drive. It does the rest on it's own.